# Relative img url issue in Sass file of Create React App generated app

Tags: css, webpack, sass, create-react-app

Here's my folder structure:

```
-- src
---- components
------ App.js
------ App.scss
---- img
------ icon-gear.png
---- styles
------ base.scss
```

Here are the relevant parts of my component (App.js):

```
import './App.scss';

class App extends Component {
```

Here are the relevant parts of my Sass file (App.scss):

```
@import '../styles/base.scss';

.App {
  .App-btnSettings {
    background-image: url('../img/icon-gear.png');
  }
}
```

I can't for the life of me get that icon-gear image path right.

When I use `../img/icon-gear.png` it bombs with:

> Module not found: Can't resolve '../img/icon-gear.png' in '/Users/rob/develop/openbazaar/openbazaar-web/src/styles/components'

When I use `../../img/icon-gear.png` it bombs with:

> ./src/components/App.scss... You attempted to import ../../img/icon-gear.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

What is the root path the image path should be relative to? I would think it's `src/components` because that's where this sass file is and that's also where I do the import (`@import '../styles/base.scss'`) at the top of the file from. But... that doesn't work (first error above).

It also seems like there's a different base path between the two different error messages.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your folder structure is incorrect.

```
-- src
---- components
------ App.js
------ App.scss
-- img
---- icon-gear.png
-- styles
---- base.scss
```

Needs to be

```
-- src
---- components
------ App.js
------ App.scss
---- img
------ icon-gear.png
---- styles
------ base.scss
```

Webpack should correctly recognize relative paths once you change this.

Also make sure you have node sass installed at the top level

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

Comment: no same issue. I would think node-sass was already installed as a dep of CRA.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-in-create-react-app-v2

Did you kill your dev server and restart it after you installed node-sass?

Comment: Yes I did. Why would explicitly installing it fix the issue if it's already installed as a dep of another dep (i assume CRA)?

Comment: Because it doesn't come pre-installed.  Read the articles I posted.

Comment: ok. Anyhow, even with it explicitly installed as a top-level dep, it still doesn't work for me. Looks like I have another issue.

Comment: also just to be clear, node-sass was always installed for me because without that image url, the file compiles fine and my app works fine. It's just choking on that url for some reason and I can't figure the correct path.

Comment: Move img and styles into src.  Webpack is probably getting confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187687/discussion-between-mark-and-robmisio).

Comment: Sorry about that. I actually did have everything in the src folder. I just misrepresented it in the question. I've updated the question.

Comment: What's weird is that even though App.scss is in src/components, it seems to output App.css in styles/components. Is that what it's configured to do?